# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS tool for buffering without polygons overlapping regions of neighboring boundaries

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer

Is there a way to create buffers around a group of polygons (vector file) in QGIS  where the overlapping buffer parts are not in the result? Please see picture example: [image: BUFFER_PIC]

I've seen a question asked recently here about a method in ArcGIS, and it would be really good to know if there is any similar tool exists in QGIS or what would be the solution in QGIS? This was the question: [Buffer Polygons without overlapping regions of neighbouring boundaries in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434355/buffer-polygons-without-overlapping-regions-of-neighbouring-boundaries-in-arcgis)

Comment: Please include relevant information in your question, since links are subject to change.

Comment: side note: the attached picture is from the linked question

Comment: Maybe having a look at this somewhat related QGIS model could give you some idea : https://plugins.qgis.org/models/8/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I might find what I need, called: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/buffer_without_overlaps/ I just need 3.22 QGIS first